# PLSQL exception in SFDC any thoughts?

Tags: visualforce, sharing

Content cannot be displayed: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-30006: resource busy; acquire with WAIT timeout expiredORA-06512: at "SLEEPY.CAPEX", line 2715ORA-06512: at line 1: SQLException while executing plsql statement: {call cApex.update_sysmodstamp(?)}([ 01pW00000004YfW, 01pW00000004YgM ][Ljava.lang.String;@57dcab05)

Cant believe i got this exception in my Inline Visualforce Page ?Anythoughts ?

Comment: Anytime you see an exception like that, you should feel free to contact salesforce support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen that error after someone has made a change to the sharing model, update to profile permissions or cascade deletion. Basically any operation that would lock access to certain administrative operations or records. The issue usually resolves itself.